# Recursively add promise await to a record key in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, promise

I have record type alias `schemaObj`

```
const schemaObj: Record<string, any> = {};
```

I have a array of strings `ref = ["abc.json", "test.json"]`

I am iterating over `ref` and for individual element calling a recursive function and the return trying to assign to same `record` `key`. This is what I am doing

```
if (ref.length > 0) {
        schemaObj[key] = await Promise.all(
          _.map(ref, async (o) => {
            return await recursiveFunction(o);
          }).flat()
        ).then((values) => {
          return values;
        });
      }
```

This serves the purpose, but I was more willing to do it in a chain sequence ( for better readability and cleaner code ). Especially on top of the same chain sequence where I am creating `ref`  something like below

```
refSchemas = [{"values":"abc.json"},{"values": "xyz"},{ "values": "test.json"}] 


_.filter(refSchemas, (o) => o.values.includes(".json"))
        .map((e) => e.values)
        .map(async (e:string) => {
          schemaObj[key] = await recursiveFunction(e);
        });
```

But this overrides the `schemaObj[key]` value. I tried the spread notation `...` but didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns values in a loop, but you don't return them. Instead of that, you assign values back to `schemaObj[key]` in every round of `map`

A possible fix could be

```
schemaObj[key] = _.filter(refSchemas, (o) => o.values.includes(".json"))
        .map((e) => e.values)
        .map(async (e:string) => {
           return await recursiveFunction(e); //return a value
        });
```

You also can use a direct [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of a library's filter `_.filter`

```
schemaObj[key] = refSchemas.filter((o) => o.values.includes(".json"))
        .map((e) => e.values)
        .map(async (e:string) => {
           return await recursiveFunction(e); //return a value
        });
```